Blender render tab is not showing model
I want to do a test render of my project, but every time I hit render image, the blender render tab appears like nothing's in there to render, just blanc... I am wondering if anyone else had this issue before and what I can do to fix it. In previous versions of this there was no problem, but now suddenly something's not right. Also, the other renders that we did all worked.

this is what I see everytime I want to render it out. Just a blank blender render tab and a crashing blender program...
If anyone can help me, that would be more than welcome.
Regards, Bas

Hello maybe you have a video strip in your Video Sequencer? If this is not the case please share the file
